# Отображение роли пользователя в представлении ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Создаю страницу с таблицей, отображающую всех пользователей. Мне необходимо в столбце рядом отобразить роли пользователей.
Пытаюсь это сделать следующим образом:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Roles.First(p => p.Value == item.Roles.ToArray()[0].RoleId))
</td>
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Шаблоны могут использоваться только с выражениями обращения к полю, обращения к свойству, индекса одномерного массива и настраиваемого индексатора с одним параметром.

Answer (score 1):

Или так

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Roles.First(p => p.Value == item.Roles.ToArray()[0].RoleId))
</td>
```

или так

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(@Model.Roles.First(p => p.Value == item.Roles.ToArray()[0].RoleId))
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы распечатать не только роли, навешанные через стандартный провайдер, например Active Directory, но и собственные, лучше использовать claims

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (identity != null)
    {
        foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
        {
            <p>@claim</p>
        }
    }
}
```